# Randomly creating areas within one country focusing on built-up area using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, point-in-polygon, random, create

I need to Randomly select 60 areas(square 2*2=4km2) within one country and it should take into account all six landscape types.

I need it to compare the build-up area changes during a few decades (time horizon).

I did it in 2 ways:
1st, easy- I used Geoprocessing-Create Random point, and then I used Buffer for each point to create a square form.
2nd way: I divided the country into 6 landscape types according to elevation (low land... high land), and for each land type, I created 10 areas using the same way: Geoprocessing-Create Random point- Buffer.

I think the 2nd way is also the wrong way because each land elevation has 10 points at the same time the area of each land elevation will have a different total area, I think it is not a logical method as well.  If I use a grid, is it a good choice? I will create a grid with a distance let's say 5 km ( to avoid overlapping by my square polygons), and then randomly choose points inside grids. But how to do it?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the first attempt met the criteria, but it's possible that the second approach did (provided that the random points were not within 1.3km of the border). Have you checked? Why do you think it's wrong? Also, the definition of "rectangular" needs to be stated, since 0.02x100km would meet the area criteria, but likely not the within criteria. Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: So now the samples are square, and you want the 60 areas to be representative of the actual landscape types (pro-rated)?  This is just stratified sampling, though if any landscape type is less than one 60th, you have a problem.  Why not make the 60 points, and test to make sure that the sample is representative, and if not, generate another set?

Comment: What do you mean by 'representative' points (areas)?